# How to programmatically search for a file inside some JAR?

Tags: java, jar, unzip

How should I search and retrieve some x.txt file from a given JAR in Java? I guess, first I need to unzip it...

Comment: .. what happens once you've unzipped it?

Comment: Do you know the name AND path of the file x.txt in the JAR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [JarInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html) to open it, iterate over it using [getNextJarEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html#getNextJarEntry%28%29) and compare names using [ZipEntry.getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getName%28%29)